# Backup my ubuntu 18.04 both (45GB) root and (1TB) home directories before resizing the root dir

Tags: 18.04, root, resize, clone, clonezilla

I have a big (42GB) root and (1TB) home (ubuntu 18.04), as the Gpartted show & df -h.

I want to back up my Ubuntu 18.04, not only copying all the files but also want all the installed packages/environments to come with it. I am doing this in preparation for resizing my root file system that is about to get full (93%).

My plan is to 1). Do backup for both my Ubuntu 18.04., all the installed environment/packages, and all the files 2). Resize my root dir 3). Reinstall my backed up Ubuntu 18.04.
But I still don't have so much idea about how to do it

My specific questions are

1. What is a good way to securely do the backup? It would be great if you can give a step by step procedures for cloning. I have never done this before.
2. How big do I have to prepare the USB/Hard drive to save the backup file? Is it need to be as big as my root+home = 1.042TB?
3. I also have another two hard drives mounted with my Ubuntu 18.04. Should I unmounted them before I start the backup process to avoid confusion?
4. Suppose that I was able to resize my root directory. Is there any way for me to install my backup environment back into my computer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it might be better idea to find what is filling up your root partition.  It is a good size and should not be filled up.  Might have wonky logs or something.

Comment: Hi @crip659, Do you know how to check the logs ? I tried to check but all I can see is that my /root is taking the space. Do you know a better way to do this ?

Comment: Disk usage analyzer should let you see what is taking space.  Then a fast google to find what can be deleted or fixed.  Most times questions about using up space is about runaway log writes.

Comment: I see. @crip659. Is it normal that my  var/log/journal takes 4.8GB and  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu takes 6.3GB ?

Comment: Mine are running about a gig less, so about normal I guess.  My root been running for about a year and half.  See if anything taking large space up.  My root is 37GB and has over 12GBs free.  Logs I think can be deleted safely, but would check first.

Comment: Backups are always a good thing. However, your problem could be solved with two simple partition resize/moves without too much chance of loosing any data. Interested in the procedure?

Comment: I decided to post an answer with steps on how to re-partition anyway. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I am so sorry. I have not yet tried the method that you suggested, but I do plan to follow it. 

It happens that my computer is still being used for various works. However, I have scheduled this task in the middle of the next month, and once I do it. I will keep you update. Nevertheless, thank you very much for putting the effort and for catching up.  Your suggestion seems very sensible.

Answer (score 0):

**My specific questions are:**

1. What is a good way to securely do the backup? It would be great if you can give a step by step procedures for cloning. I have never done this before.

Most people use Clonezilla.

2. How big do I have to prepare the USB/Hard drive to save the backup file? Is it need to be as big as my root+home = 1.042TB?

For a clone, the backup disk needs to be a large as the source disk.

3. I also have another two hard drives mounted with my Ubuntu 18.04. Should I unmounted them before I start the backup process to avoid confusion?

Doesn't hurt.

4. Suppose that I was able to resize my root directory. Is there any way for me to install my backup environment back into my computer?

More difficult answer. Probably not necessary if the resizing goes without problems.

---

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **resize** the p3 partition by the right side and reduce the partition by 30-50G
- **move** the p3 partition all the way right
- **resize** the p2 partition by the right side, and extend it all the way to the right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: @heynnena, would it not be better to find what is filling up root space first?  A 40GB root should be big enough for most people if they also have a /home partition.

Comment: @crip659 Yes it would. But in looking at OP's `Disk Usage Analyzer` output, there's nothing apparent, other than MATLAB and CUDA. /var/log and others look fine. There are a couple of possible rouge tensorrt files there.

Comment: Miss he added that, i will go now.